# Why does jQuery return undefined when I use .prop() to find a custom data attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have this HTML generated dynamically via JavaScript:

```js
$(".task-status").live("click", function () {

    alert("data-id using prop: " + $(this).prop("data-id"))
    alert("data-id using data: " + $(this).data("id"))

    alert("data-TaskId using prop: " + $(this).prop("data-TaskId"))
    alert("data-TaskId using data: " + $(this).data("TaskId"))

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blue-button-bg task-status" data-id="2" data-TaskId="2">
 Scheduled
</div>
```

When I write `alert($(this).prop("data-id"))` in a click event it is undefined, but when I do this `alert($(this).data("id"))` it gives me **"2"** as expected.

If I change attribute `data-id` to `data-TaskId` it returns **undefined** for both `prop()` and `data()`.

Can anybody explain why is it so?

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f8LqvoL1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `data-*` attributes are not assigned to DOM element properties.

Use `attr()` rather than `prop()`:

```
alert("data-id using prop: " + $(this).attr("data-id"))
alert("data-id using data: " + $(this).data("id"))

alert("data-TaskId using prop: " + $(this).attr("data-TaskId"))
alert("data-TaskId using data: " + $(this).data("TaskId"))
```

Your `data-TaskId` data attribute will be converted to lower case. Upper case letters are only used by jQuery's `.data()` API to convert hypenated attributes `data-task-id` to camel-cased properties: `.data().taskId`

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f8LqvoL1/5/)

Comment: what you mean? you means to day `prop()` not works on dynamic elements

Comment: `prop()` is used to get a property of a DOM element. Your `data-*` attributes aren't properties, they are attributes, so you use `attr()`.

Comment: and why in 2nd case `data()` also gives undefined?

Comment: Because when caching your data attributes, jQuery will convert your attribute names to lower case.

Comment: It's not jQuery that does this , it is the HTML that got rendered in the DOM automatically converts data attribute in `uppercase` to `lowercase` even if you write that in `uppercase` in your code . @EhsanSajjad

Comment: you write `id` in `uppercase` . See it will change into `lowercase` . That's the `HTML5` changes not the jQuery @EhsanSajjad

Answer (score 1):

**[YOUR UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f8LqvoL1/4/) :**

Try using `.attr()` rather `.prop()` . Secondly the **TaskId** should be written in `lowercase` . See below :-

```
$(".task-status").live("click", function () {

  alert("data-id using prop: " + $(this).attr("data-id"))
  alert("data-id using data: " + $(this).data("id"))

  alert("data-TaskId using prop: " + $(this).attr("data-TaskId"))
  alert("data-TaskId using data: " + $(this).data("taskid"))

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `attr` method instead of prop.

```
$(".task-status").live("click", function () {

    alert("data-id using prop: " + $(this).attr("data-id"))
    alert("data-id using data: " + $(this).data("id"))

    alert("data-TaskId using prop: " + $(this).attr("data-TaskId"))
    alert("data-TaskId using data: " + $(this).data("TaskId"))

});
```

Answer (score -1):

HTML5 data attribute must be lowercase, cannot load camel-case attributes

http://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-data-attributes/

Also you can use $("selector").data("lowecase att without data-")